# All elements still have menuBar style? (<?php include...>)

Tags: html, css

So this is my Menu Bar code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href = menuBarStyle.css rel = "stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">   
<div class = "menu">

<ul class = "bar">
    <li><a href = "index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Music</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href = "djdizzstart.php">DJ Dizz Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "djdizzspotify.php">Spotify</a></li>
        <li><a href = "djdizzsoundcloud.php">SoundCloud</a></li>
        <li><a href = "djdizzitunes.php">iTunes</a></li>               
        </ul>           
    </li>            
    <li><a>Learn</a>     
        <ul>          
        <li><a>JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a>Java</a></li>
        <li><a>Web</a></li>
        <li><a>SQL Databases</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Credits</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Design & Code</a></li>
            <li><a>Music</a></li>
            <li><a>Marketing</a></li>
            <li><a>Hosting</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>
    <li><a id = "login">Login</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</html>
```

And this it's style:

```
import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Amatic+SC:700|Hind+Siliguri|Shadows+Into+Light');

body {
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    min-width:800px;       
    width: auto !important;  
    width:800px; 
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;    
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    left: 50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;       
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li: hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
#login {
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
#login:hover {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
#menu {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now all i want is to make all other elements independent from that style, but the  `ul li` in my following code always has the style from my `navigationBar`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head><title>DJ Dizz iTunes</title></head>
<?php include ("menuBar.html"); ?>
<link href = "style.css" rel = stylesheet>
<body>
    <div id="Startpage">
        <p style="text-align: center">iTunes</p>
    </div>
    <div id="itunes" style="text-align:center">
        <a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/artist/dj-dizz/1204428323?mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/assets/shared/badges/de-de/music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:200px;height:55px;"></a>
    </div>
    <ul id="songs">
        <li><a href = "https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/staying-down/1434126188?i=1434126382&mt=1&app=music">Staying Down</a></li>
        <li><a href = "https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/its-me/1270058662?i=1270058790&mt=1&app=music">It's Me</a></li>    
    </ul>           
</body>
</html>
```

So now the other `ul li` elements with the iTunes href's are not changing at all, they just stay the same as the `navigationBar`. I tried classes and id's but none works. All of the files are in `.php` except for my `menuBar`, this is `.html`

Thanks for your answers

Lars (Beginner)

Comment: <link href = menuBarStyle.css rel = "stylesheet"> missing the quotes on the href
<link href = "menuBarStyle.css" rel = "stylesheet">

Comment: thanks man, but that wasn solving my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navigation has the class "bar", so you need to specify that class in your CSS to target that element only and not ALL of the uls on the page. Ex:

```
ul.bar {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
... etc ...
}

ul.bar li {
float: left;
width: 200px;
... etc ...
}
```

Do that for all of your ul rules in your CSS and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanls a lot maan! Saved my day <33333